# Adding polling mechanism to a http call in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, service, polling

Given a service that is requesting an object (type Status) and expects a response with info for a JOB_ID passed as an argument, how could I add polling mechanism in order to get this call done every minute?

```
  fetchJobLastStatus$(JOB_ID): Observable<Status> {
  const url = `//API CALL//`;
    return this.http.get<Status>(url).pipe(
      map(data => {
        if (data) {
          console.log(data)
        }
        return <Status>data;
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polling http call for every minute.

```
fetchJobLastStatus$(JOB_ID): Observable<Status> {
  const url = `//API CALL//`;
  return timer(0, 60000).pipe(switchMap(_ => this.http.get<Status>(url)));
}
```

Comment: You can approve my answer then :)